# Is there any paper shown how to solve an one class SVM by SMO type algorithm

Tags: svm, outliers

The one class SVM can be used as an outlier rejection. An example can be found on. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3041295/ Generally one class SVM is shown as a constrained quadratic optimization problem.

Support vector machine (SVM) optimization problem can be solved by quadratic programming. However, we have another efficient (low memory requirement) algorithm sequential minimal optimization (SMO) for solving SVM. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/59ee/e096b49d66f39891eb88a6c84cc89acba12d.pdf

The question: is there any paper which shows how to solve one class SVM by SMO type algorithm? Any reference or suggestion would be highly;y appreciated.

Comment: See section 3.3 in https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4344146

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The abstract of the paper "A Fast Learning Algorithm for One-Class Support Vector Machine" by Jia Jiong and Zhang Hao-ran published in: Third International Conference on Natural Computation (ICNC 2007) is as follows:

> Support vector machine (SVM) is a powerful tool to solve classification problems, this paper proposes a fast sequential minimal optimization (SMO) algorithm for training one-class support vector regression (OCSVM), firstly gives a analytical solution to the size two quadratic programming (QP) problem, then proposes a new heuristic method to select the working set which leads to algorithm's faster convergence. The simulation results indicate that the proposed SMO algorithm can reduce the training time of OCSVM, and the performance of proposed SMO algorithm is better than that of original SMO algorithm.